# Chrome Issues - Language? Weird characters in preferences and sites

Tags: google-chrome, macbook-pro

I'm using a Macbook with Chrome, when I go into the settings it appears as below:

[image]

I've tried:

- Running Malware Bytes
- Running Avast Security
- Deleting Chrome and Reinstalling

Has anybody come across this?

Other browsers seem fine, it's just Chrome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried changing the default fonts in Chrome's settings? If you right-click the garbled text (or Mac equivalent?) and "Inspect" does it name the font?

Comment: Dude, you are awesome, yeah for some reason Roboto font was messed up even though it was downloaded from Google Fonts. Deleting the font fixed the issue. Thanks man!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(comment converted to answer as it resulted in a fix for the problem)

Have you tried changing the default fonts in Chrome's settings? If you right-click the garbled text (or Mac equivalent?) and "Inspect" does it name the font?

Answer (score 0):

The Roboto font was missing from my iMac Font Book app. I reinstalled it from the google font website and then remove the font and everything came back to normal in Chrome. Hope this help!

Answer (score -1):

Had same issue and after I delete all Roboto fonts from Font Book app everything came to normal in Chrome!